# Why does `scala.util.Try(date)` not return `Failure` when `date` is not defined?

Tags: scala, error-handling, functional-programming

Why does `scala.util.Try(date)` not return `Failure` as I would expect like how `scala.util.Try(3/0)` returns `Failure(java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero)`?

This is what I'm seeing in my REPL

```
scala> scala.util.Try(3/0)
res5: scala.util.Try[Int] = Failure(java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero)

scala> scala.util.Try(date)
                      ^
       error: not found: value date
```

Comment: `Try(x)` will return `Failure` if `x` throws. Throwing an exception is a **runtime** event. If `x` doesn't exist then that's a **compile-time** error. In that case `Try` is never even invoked because the compiler has nothing to pass as the specified argument.

Comment: Thank you, this was the best answer so far. I would accept your answer as the best, but it's a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the expression `Try(x)` where, in this case, `x` can be a variable to be evaluated, or a function to be invoked, or a block of code to be executed. This expression will return `Failure` if `x` (whatever it is) throws an exception.

Throwing an exception is a **runtime** event.

If, on the other hand, `x` is a reference to a variable or function that doesn't exist, or `x` as a block of code can't be compiled because it has a syntax error, then that's a **compile-time** error. In that case the `Try()` call is never even invoked because the compiler has nothing to pass as the specified argument.

The REPL (Read-Evaluate-Print-Loop) can obscure the difference between the two types of errors because the compile->run (evaluate->print) happens, one after the other, with each line of input.

Comment: Thank you. It was this line that made it click in my head, "..the Try() call is never even invoked because the compiler has nothing to pass as the specified argument." Much better than just memorizing that Try only returns Failure for runtime errors.

Answer (score 4):

It's sort of difficult to tell the difference because runtime happens right after compile time in the REPL, but it's because missing value date is a compile time error, and a `Failure` represents a runtime error.

Answer (score 2):

```
scala.util.Try(date)
not found: value date
```

is silly compiler error (you have not declared date varialble and you are using it) not Runtime Exception Where as

```
scala.util.Try(3/0) 

Failure(java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero): scala.util.Try[Int]
```

runtime exception

See another examples : 
Example 1 :

```
val dateFmt1 = "yyyyy   xx"
scala.util.Try {  
    val date = new Date
    val sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFmt1)
    sdf.format(date)
}
```

will throw RuntimeException like this

```
    Failure(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'x'): scala.util.Try[String]
```

Example 2 :

```
val dateFmt = "yyyy-MM-dd"
scala.util.Try {  
    val date = new Date
    val sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFmt)
    sdf.format(date)
}
```

will result :

```
Success(2020-04-30): scala.util.Try[String]
```

See exception handing [article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/scala-demo-different-ways-exception-handling-ram-ghadiyaram/) here for better understanding